# What does frame.__init__ do? - tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

I am watching Sentdex's Tkinter tutorial and there are some related problems that arise:

> 1. **Basic Class Questions that I'm just new to: How come `Frame` follows after the declaration of the Window class (sorry for a basic class question)?** **How is `self.pack` working without specifying what to pack?**
> 2. **What does `frame.__init__` contribute to this code?**

The code is this:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='LightBlue')

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.master.geometry('400x400')

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        quitButton = Button(self, text='Quit')
        quitButton.place(x=0, y=0)


root = Tk()

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame is in brackets so that the class Window can inherit the methods of the tkinter.Frame class.
The Frame.**init** function initialises the class as a tkinter Frame.
The self.pack() line packs the Frame into self.master, which was created a couple of lines before.

Have a look at some basic classes and build up from there.

I did this tutorial a little while ago and found that I had to spend a little time having a look at classes first. I used some youtube videos I think, good luck!

Comment: `Frame` isn't "passed to the class". The proper terminology is that the class is _inheriting_ from the `Frame` class.

Answer (score 4):

The `class Window` inherits from `tk.Frame`, this is what `(Frame)` after `Window` means.
In such a situation, `Window` is also a `tk.Frame`, hence when calling `pack()` on `self`, it is in essence packing itself.

It is likely less confusing to avoid star imports:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window(tk.Frame):                           # <-- avoid star imports

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(master, bg='LightBlue')  # <-- use super instead of hardcoding the parent class

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.master.geometry('400x400')
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', 
                                     command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit_button.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```